# Filtering an Array based on contains - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to write a bit of code which will take a copy of my main array, then filter itself to only contain the desired values.

```
func filterArray(filter : String)
{
    var filtered : [Data]  = mainArray
    filtered = filtered.filter { mainArray.contains(filter) } 
}
```

Is it possible with the filter method? Or should I loop through my mainArray and if it matches my condition append it to the filtered Array?

Comment: Any reason for the unexplained down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way

```
func filterArray(filter : String)
{
    let filtered = mainArray.filter { $0.contains(filter) }
print(filtered)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like following:

```
func filterArray(filter : String)
{
    let filtered = mainArray.filter { ($0.contains(filter)) }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is the different between your answer and my answer.

Comment: Nothing you have added before one minute while I am writing the answer.